# Magento 2 - Where to find the complete REST API documentation

Tags: api, rest, magento2

It seems like the [official Magento 2 REST API Documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/) is not complete.

I found this code in a application of one of our ex colleagues:

```
protected function addItemToCart($cartId, $cartItem)
{
    return $this->client->request('POST', "carts/{$cartId}/items", [
        'json' => [
            'cartItem' => $cartItem,
        ],
    ]);
}
```

But I can't find any documenation for `carts/{$cartId}/items`.

The nearest I can find is: `/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items`

Where can I find the documentation for `carts/{$cartId}/items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a POST method available on the [`carts/{$cartId}/items`](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/cartscartIditems#operation/GetV1CartsCartIdItems) route.

---

So there's probably something else going on, could be one of these:

- Actually you're using [`POST /V1/carts/{quoteId}/items`](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/cartsquoteIditems#operation/PostV1CartsQuoteIdItems)
- Your ex-colleagues extended the default API so the POST on `carts/{$cartId}/items` is a **custom endpoint**
- You are using a very old Magento version in which this was available.

---

Consider using the [ReDoc Documentation](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin) page.

Comment: Yes, I think he was using the route which you have posted. Thx!